# Как добавить линию на график highcharts в R

Tags: r, график

Нужно добавить линию, параллельную оси X, на график, построенный с помощью пакета `highcharter`.

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример данных и код построения графика. Уберите лишний код, который не относится к вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используется параметр `plotLines` функции `hc_xAxis` или `hc_yAxis`. Поддерживаются следующие параметры: `label` (аннотация), `color` (цвет), `width` (толщина линии), `value` (координата оси). См. также документацию highcharts (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines).

Пример описан в документации к пакету highcharter: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html

```
library(highcharter)

data(diamonds, mpg, package = "ggplot2")

hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Month in x Axis"),
           opposite = TRUE,
           plotLines = list(
             list(label = list(text = "This is a plotLine"),
                  color = "#FF0000",
                  width = 2,
                  value = 2),
             list(label = list(text = "This is a plotLine"),
                  color = "#FF0000",
                  width = 2,
                  value = 6))) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature in y Axis"),
           opposite = TRUE,
           minorTickInterval = "auto",
           minorGridLineDashStyle = "LongDashDotDot",
           showFirstLabel = FALSE,
           showLastLabel = FALSE,
           plotLines = list(
             list(label = list(text = "This is a plotBand"),
                  color = "#FF0000",
                  width = 2,
                  value = 30)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Добавить линию на график:

Используем функцию plotlines в атрибутах xAxis or yAxis. Значение через 2 list ()

xAxis(
... 
Plotlines = list ( list (
... 
) 
)